How to lowercase all routes including areas and Identity in ASP.NET Core 7 MVC?
I have /Admin/Home
But I need /admin/home
I tried many methods and nothing worked. I've been sitting on this for a long time, I hope someone can help me.
I tried using the following:
services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);

Also this:
services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true); 

It does not affect the appearance of most links in any way.

Have you add services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true); before services.AddMvc();?

Does this answer your question? How do you enforce lowercase routing in ASP.NET Core?
